# Problems downloading a page updated everyday

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm developing an application on GAE that fetches a web page and searches it for a link.
This page gets updated every morning, so a cron job is executed each morning every 15 minutes for a couple of hours, to obtain current day's page.

Here's the problem: if at the first execution of the cron job the application finds the older page (yesterday's one), it keeps fetching that one, although a new page is available at the same URL.
Seems that a cache is used somewhere, but I can't disable it.

The code that the application uses for downloading the page is simply Java I/O:

```
    InputStream input = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    URL url = new URL("http://www.page.url.net");
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(0);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (httpResponseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            input = conn.getInputStream();
            output = writeByteArrayOutputStreamFromInputStream(input);
        } else {
            throw new IOException("response code " + httpResponseCode);
        }
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            output.close();
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid caching, I suggest to use this simple trick: add a "fake" query parameter to the end of the query string, for example if the page you are fetching is

http://www.page.url.net

add a parameter named dummy= so the url becomes:

http://www.page.url.net?dummy=2013-05-25

Just be sure the "dummy" paramater is not actually interpreted by the remote server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: well, because the cache uses the full uri as "key" for the cached resource. So if you add a dummy query parameter, you are actually simulating that the requested resource is always different, so the cache always miss.